# extracting part of xml and merge into another in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

my xml file name my.xml has contents like

```
<xml>
<parent a="1">
<child1>val1</child1>
<chid2>val2</child2>
</parent>
```

I need the part

```
<child1>val1</child1>
<chid2>val2</child2>
```

as is to insert into another xml file which has contents

```
 <xml>
    <parent a="1">
    <child1>val3</child1>
    <chid2>val4</child2>
    </parent>
```

to make it look like

```
 <parent a="1">
    <child1>val3</child1>
    <chid2>val4</child2>
    <child1>val1</child1>
    <chid2>val2</child2>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

​def from = """<parent a="1">  
  <child1>val1</child1>   
  <child2>val2</child2>   
</parent>
"""

def to = """<parent a="1">     
  <child1>val3</child1>     
  <child2>val4</child2>     
</parent>"""

def fromxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(from)  
def toxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(to)  

toxml[0].children() << fromxml.children()

println XmlUtil.serialize(toxml)​
```

Comment: my contents are two different xml files. ur parseText is probably not considering them as xml

Comment: parseText parse a xml from a string. It shoud work if you are using xml. If you are not using a valid xml file, you should probably edit your question with the kind of data you have ?

Comment: well that's ok but i don't see my new file being modified.  so i am not is it because it is not writing back to file ?

Comment: If you want to write to a file, you can use `new File("my.xml").withOutputStream { XmlUtil.serialize(toxml, it) }`

Comment: why do you need it here?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = """<parent a="1">
  <child1>val1</child1>
  <child2>val2</child2>
  </parent>"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( s ) 
assert 'val1' == xml.child1.text()
assert 'val2' == xml.child2.text()
assert 'child2' == xml.child2.name()
```

Comment: this will give val1 and val2. I need with whole tags

Comment: `xml.child1` gives you the whole node

Comment: how to do i get both the children at once? as i need to insert them as is to another xml

Comment: use `each` as per http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html